# How to change the font of an svg file

Tags: html, css, image, svg

so I've got an svg image that's got some text in it. I need to change that font to Lato.

My svg file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg width="195px" height="35px" viewBox="0 0 195 35" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<defs>
  <style type="text/css">
    @font-face {
        font-family: "Lato";
        src: url("../fonts/Lato-Regular.ttf") format("truetype");
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
        font-display: swap;
    }   
  </style>
</defs>
    <title>logo@3x</title>
    <g id="Symbols" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <g id="header" transform="translate(-110.000000, -27.000000)" fill="#FFFFFF">
            <g id="logo" transform="translate(110.000000, 27.000000)">
                <text id="MYTEXT" font-family="Lato" font-size="16" font-weight="700">
                    <tspan x="0.4" y="32">MYTEXT</tspan>
                </text>
                <g id="Group-2-Copy" transform="translate(131.000000, 0.000000)">
                    <path d="M18.5,3.55271368e-14 L46,31 L39.672,31 L18.5,7.13337259 L12.409,14 L6.081,14 L18.5,3.55271368e-14 Z" id="Combined-Shape"></path>
                    <path d="M27.75707,0 L55,31 L0.514140039,31 L0.515140039,30.999 L48.9974668,31 L24.6656839,3.52056535 L24.00714,4.266 L27.75707,0 Z" id="Combined-Shape-Copy-4"></path>
                    <path d="M36.75707,0 L64,31 L9.51414004,31 L9.51514004,30.999 L57.9974668,31 L33.6656839,3.52056535 L33.00714,4.266 L36.75707,0 Z" id="Combined-Shape-Copy-5"></path>
                </g>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

As you can see, I tried adding a `<style>` tag within the `<defs>` tag and pulling in the font that I've set elsewhere.

This hasn't worked however, is there something I'm missing?
I'm dispaying the image like so:

```
<img src={logo} alt="imh logo" />
```

I also tried using an `object` tag and displaying it like so:

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data={logo}>
     <img src={logo} alt="imh logo" />
</object>
```

This hasn't changed the font either! I'd appreciate any help you might have, thanks!

Comment: Images must be self contained so you'll need to convert the font to a data URL. Your current external reference won't work.

Comment: @RobertLongson Okay, any tips on how to do that?

Comment: What is it that you don't understand?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme